# Как работает метод insert в в классе Vector в с++?

Tags: c++

В методе insert класса Vector нужно передать итератор указывающий на позицию в которую ты хочешь поместить элемент, я правильно понимаю что для того чтобы поместить тот или иной элемент в заданную позицию нужно  итерироваться через весь список пока не найдется нужная позиция ?

Comment: Если вы ищете конкретный элемент в векторе, чтобы в его место поместить новый, то да, нужно итерироваться по списку, чтобы найти эту позицию.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, нет я имею ввиду  к примеру  у меня есть вектор из  10 элементов и я решил вставить элемент со значением 1 в середину вектора таким образом: vector.insert(vector.begin()+5,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `vector` представляет собой динамический массив и реализует итераторы с произвольным доступом. Соответственно доступ к любой позиции всегда производится за одну операцию. Другое дело, что для того, чтобы вставить новый элемент на требуемую позицию, может потребоваться передвинуть элементы, стоящие справа от него, а то и перевыделить новый массив, если в старом не хватает места.

Comment: зачем тогда в методе добавлять ссылку на итератор можно же просто позицию обозначить?

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg потому что в стандартной библиотеке много контейнеров, и у разных контейнеров итераторы с разными свойствами. Но, в зависимости от типа итератора у них есть и общие свойства. Поэтому если вы используете итераторы, вы можете писать более обобщенные алгоритмы, которые могут работать с разными контейнерами, а не только с например с вектором.

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg Это хороший вопрос. Многих методов на практике действительно явно не хватает.

Comment: @Slava А что плохого было бы в существовании перегрузки `insert`, принимающей индекс вместо итератора? То, что итераторы являются более обобщенной концепцией, не означает отсутствие необходимости в использовании индексов. По мне таких методов явно не хватает. Что удивительно, в `std::string` они же есть.

Comment: @VTT интерфейс не стоит загромождать дублирующейся функциональностью без необходимости. В `std::string` была необходимость - обеспечить обратную совместимость.

Comment: @Slava Ну нет, куда лучше не загромождать пользовательский код. Ведь дублирования в пользовательском коде выходит куда больше. И отчего не сделали методы как в `string` - непонятно.

Comment: @VTT `std::string` разработана как строка со строковыми методами, затем добавлены методы, чтобы со строкой можно было работать как с контейнером. Для вектора этого не делали.

Comment: @Slava Я не вижу никаких причин этого не сделать. Зачем заставлять людей каждый раз писать `vector.begin() + index`? Полезных на практике перегрузок и функций жестко не хватает (это я не только вектор имею ввиду).

Comment: Товарищи, не отклоняйтесь от темы, меня интересует одно при вставке элемента по заданному индексу  происходит за O(1) или за O(n), где n заданный индекс?

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg сложность можно посмотреть в [описании](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), она может несколько рознится для разных перегрузок. Но вообще линейно

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg сложность зависит от того, сколько элементов находится за вставляемым и необходимо ли увеличивать capacity при добавлении элемента.

Comment: заранее прошу прощения за возможно идиотский вопрос ,но есть ли в с++ коллекции которые имеют доступ к элементам по индексу за O(1)  и при этом вставляют элемент по индексу тоже за O(1)?

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg Подобное было бы слишком хорошо, что бы быть правдой ). Но `std::unordered_map` может к этому приближаться (хотя в крайних случаях будет медленее).

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg возможно `std::deque` близок к этому.

Answer (score 0):

> зачем тогда в методе добавлять ссылку на итератор можно же просто позицию обозначить?

Ответ на этот вопрос проще дать на примере. Например я хочу имплементировать функцию, которая вставляет элемент в n-ю позицию:

```
template<class Container,class T>
void insert_into_pos( Container &c, size_t pos, T obj )
{
    if( pos >= c.size() ) throw std::runtime_error( "invalid position" );
    c.insert( std::next( c.begin(), pos ), std::move( obj ) );
}
```

Эта функция будет работать с многими контейнерами, такими как `std::vector` `std::list` `std::deque` и пр. Если бы в векторе был доступен только метод с индексом, такая функция бы не работала с многими другими контейнерами.

Comment: Тут идет важное предусловие - *код должен работать со многими контейнерами* - которое позволяет не касаться неудобной ситуации, когда код должен работать только с векторами. Такой пример демонстрирует почему есть методы для работы и итераторами, но ничего не поясняет почему нет методов для работы с индексами.

Comment: @VTT потому что через метод с итераторами легко имплементируется метод с индексами и разработчики библиотеки не видели необходимости перегружать интерфейс.

Comment: Такое объяснения выглядит крайне малоубедительно... *не видели необходимости* - как же они могли не видеть необходимости, когда использование индексов является типичным сценарием при работе с вектором? *перегружать интерфейс* - что вообще значит "перегружать"? и если они так боялись не "перегрузить интерфейс", то почему в нем оказались такой бессмысленный метод как `max_size` или те же `cbegin` / `cend`? ведь через метод с `begin` легло имплементируется метод с const `begin`. Ведь легко писать `std::as_const(c).begin()` раз легло `std::next(c.begin(), pos)`? Или `*c.begin()` вместо `c.front()`

Comment: @VTT "Ведь легко писать std::as_const(c).begin()" вообще-то `std::as_const` появилась в C++17, а `std::vector::cbegin()` в С++11. Поэтому легко нельзя. Насчет как они могли не видеть, я не знаю, я стандартную библиотеку не разабатывал, ко мне притензии предъявлять смысла нет, я просто сообщаю по факту.